# Sort array with rsort() but keep titles

Tags: php

For example, if I sort this array:

```
$array = array(
    "cool"=>100,
    "lol"=>7,
    "wow"=>50
);

rsort($array);
```

It removes the array key names:

```
$array = array(
    0=>100,
    1=>50
    2=>7,
);
```

How can I sort and keep the array names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

arsort: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php

same as what you've got, but asort and arsort keep the index association.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   $array = array(
        "cool"=>100,
        "lol"=>7,
        "wow"=>50
    );
arsort ($array);
print_r($array);
?>

   Array ( [cool] => 100 [wow] => 50 [lol] => 7 )
```

You can find more [array sorting functions](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)